# Data Wrangling Using Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Using Dplyr, I am trying to find which country has the largest increase in wealth between 2002 and 2006 from the following data.

```
  Country   wealth_2002           wealth_2004          wealth_2006
 Country_A      1000                  1600                  2200           
 Country_B      1200                  1300                  1800             
 Country_C      1400                  1100                  1200             
 Country_D      1500                  1000                  1100             
 Country_E      1100                  1800                  1900
```

To get the country's name, I have used

```
largest_increase <- df %>%
 group_by(Country) %>%
 filter(max(wealth_2006 - wealth_2002)) %>%
```

And this gives me

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
 Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector
```

I would be really grateful if someone can help me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this. I am very new to R so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `filter(row_number() == which.max(...))`

Comment: `slice(which.max(...))` is what you need

Comment: You can just sort: `df %>% arrange(desc(wealth_2006 - wealth_2002))`. Add a column first if you like: `df %>% mutate(change = wealth_2006 - wealth_2002) %>% arrange(desc(change))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how `filter` works - you need to provide a logical "test" for each row, if it passes, it will keep the row. Also no real need to `group_by` country since each country is already its own row. Try something like this, where you calculate and store the wealth change for each country then keep the country/countries which have that max value:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(
  text = "
  Country   wealth_2002           wealth_2004          wealth_2006
  Country_A      1000                  1600                  2200
  Country_B      1200                  1300                  1800
  Country_C      1400                  1100                  1200
  Country_D      1500                  1000                  1100
  Country_E      1100                  1800                  1900
  ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df %>%
  mutate(wealth_change = wealth_2006 - wealth_2002) %>% 
  filter(wealth_change == max(wealth_change)) %>% 
  pull(Country) # gives us the Country column
```

Output:

```
[1] "Country_A"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Base R you can use `which.max` to index your country column:

```
# This is my dummy data, you can ignore it
country <- c("Sweden", "Finland")
X1 <- c(1050, 1067)
X2 <- c(1045, 1069)
DF <- data.frame(country, X1, X2)
# Modify this to suit
DF$country[which.max(DF$X2- DF$X1)]
```

So for yours it would be:

```
df$Country[which.max(df$wealth_2006 - df$wealth_2002)]
```

Comment: I've shown it using base R because, as you are new to R, I'd like to stress how important it is to become comfortable using base R, it will help you become versatile with problem solving

Answer (score 1):

Use `dput(data)` to help answers.

```
structure(list(Country = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Country_A", 
"Country_B", "Country_C", "Country_D", "Country_E"), class = "factor"), 
    wealth_2002 = c(1000L, 1200L, 1400L, 1500L, 1100L), wealth_2004 = c(1600L, 
    1300L, 1100L, 1000L, 1800L), wealth_2006 = c(2200L, 1800L, 
    1200L, 1100L, 1900L)), .Names = c("Country", "wealth_2002", 
"wealth_2004", "wealth_2006"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

library(dplyr)
data %>% 
mutate(delta = wealth_2006 - wealth_2004) %>% #Create a new variable called delta with mutate
arrange(desc(delta)) %>% #sort descending by 'delta' 
head(1) #return the top line.. pull out the specific value if needed
```

This will return the top row... of the greatest change.

Country A has a change of 600

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `top_n` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% top_n(1,wealth_2006 - wealth_2002)

#     Country wealth_2002 wealth_2004 wealth_2006
# 1 Country_A        1000        1600        2200
```